# Can we find the eigenvalues of this block matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

Suppose that $M$ is an $m \times m$ matrix. Can we find the eigenvalues of the following block matrix?

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} -I & M\\ M^T & -I\end{bmatrix}$$

in terms of the eigenvalues of $M$?

Comment: $M$ does not have eigenvalues if $m\neq n$.

Comment: You can use the Schur complement to relate the eigenvalues $\neq -1$ of $B$ to the eigenvalues of $M^TM$ (or, equivalently, the singular values of $M$) which are not $0$. Also, $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ if and only if $0$ is an eigenvalue of $M^TM$.

Comment: When $M$ is a real square matrix, the eigenvalues of $B$ are $-1\pm s_i$, where $s_1,\ldots,s_n$ are the singular values of $M$. They are functions of singular values rather than eigenvalues of $M$.

Comment: How does this relate to linear programming?

Answer (score 0):

You can relate the eigenvalues of $B$ to those of $M^TM$. First of all, we have
$$
(B-\lambda)\binom x y = \binom 0 0\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad My = (1+\lambda)x\quad\text{and}\quad M^Tx = (1+\lambda)y.
$$
From here, it is quite elementary to show that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ if and only if $(1+\lambda)^2$ is an eigenvalue of $M^TM$. This also shows you that if $B$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then also $-2-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$. That is, the eigenvalues of $B$ are symmetric with respect to the point $-1$.

Even if $M$ is square, you can in general not relate the eigenvalues of $B$ to those of $M$ (except the zero eigenvalue). Only if $M$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ if and only if $|1+\lambda|$ (i.e., the distance of $\lambda$ to $-1$) is an eigenvalue of $M$.

Comment: I get how $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ implies that $(\lambda + 1)^2$ is an eigenvalue of $M^TM$ and $MM^T$; but I don't get how the reverse implication works . . .

Comment: If $MM^Tx = (1+\lambda)^2x$, put $y = \tfrac 1{1+\lambda}M^Tx$.